# Failed to load ApplicationContext. Can not create integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing

I try to create integration test for this REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = {"/api/reports", "/api"})
public class DependencyReportController {

private final DependencyDifferenceService differenceService;

public DependencyReportController(DependencyDifferenceService differenceService) {
    this.differenceService = differenceService;
}

@GetMapping(path = {"/dependencies/difference", "/deps/diff"},
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ServiceDependenciesReport get() {
    return differenceService.getAllDiffs();
}


}
```

My test, where I try to check status:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DependencyReportController.class)
public class DependencyReportControllerApiTest {
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private DependencyDifferenceService differenceService;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    ServiceDependenciesReport report = new ServiceDependenciesReport();
    report.setElapsed("elapsed");
    report.setSuccess(true);
    when(differenceService.getAllDiffs()).thenReturn(report);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/dependencies/difference")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
}



 }
```

And it does not work. Full stacktrace:

> Description:
>
> Field monitoringProperties MonitoringApplication required a bean of
>   type 'MonitoringProperties' that could not be found.
>        The injection point has the following annotations:
>                     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> ```
>  Action:
>  Consider defining a bean of type 'MonitoringProperties' in your configuration.
>  2020-01-20 12:40:28.884 ERROR 6388 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
> ```
>
> allowing TestExecutionListener 
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@35e2d654]
>   to prepare test instance [DependencyReportControllerApiTest@44b940a2]
>        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) 
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>                     at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]
>                     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]
>                     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]
>                     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'monitoringApplication': Unsatisfied 
>   dependency expressed through field 'monitoringProperties'; nested 
>   exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
>   qualifying bean of type 'MonitoringProperties' available: expected at 
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
>   annotations: 
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>                        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]*

I never write integration tests and don't understand what am I doing wrong? What problem it can be? As I understand I should add @ComponentScan or smth like this?

Comment: Add the completet stacktrace

Comment: Failed to load ApplicationContext is too general exception, usually the reason is in the stacktrace, so please add the stacktrace

Comment: ok, it is done.

Comment: How are you providing MonitoringProperties ?

Comment: @MandarDharurkar it is configuration, it sets in DependencyDifferenceService constructor

Comment: Integration test is not able to load Mockebean of MonitoringProperties bean , can you add it in  intergration test ? that might solve your problem.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar Where I should add it? MonitoringProperties is not mock, no?

Comment: you can load Monitoring Properties in same way you load it for normal application startup. or create a mockbean and provide sample values in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to write Integration Test use `SpringBootTest`

> @SpringBootTest annotation will load the fully ApplicationContext

while

> @WebMvcTest annotation will load only the controller layer of the application.